# PostgreSQL treating the same values as different

Tags: sql, postgresql, floating-point, comparison, precision

So in this example the SQL is returning a row that has the columns "quantidade" and "quantidade_reservada", each containing the value "110", type double precision:

[image: ...]

When I try to apply a condition to retrieve only results where "quantidade" is not equal to "quantidade_reservada", PostgreSQL does not seem to differentiate the numbers.

How is 110 different from 110?

Comment: Double precision issue? Can you show more decimals somehow?

Comment: `double` is an **approximate** data type and is subject to many unpleasant surprises. More details here: http://floating-point-gui.de/ If you want to retrieve and compare the same values that you store, you should use `decimal` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Floating-Point Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT):

> The data types real and double precision are inexact, variable-precision numeric types.

Try

```
where round(quantidade::numeric, 2) != round(quantidade_reservada::numeric, 2)
```

[Arbitrary Precision Numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the numbers' values and their representation in pgAdmin.
What you are seeing in the pgAdmin is a round display of the values to 2 digits scale.

```
with t (x,y) as (select 102/300::numeric(23,20),101/300::numeric(23,20)) 

select  x
       ,y
       ,case when x=y then 'Y' else 'N' end     as is_equale
       ,x-y                                     as "x-y"
       ,(x-y)*1000                              as "(x-y)*100"

from    t
;
```

pgAdmin results:

```
x       y       is_equale   x-y     (x-y)*100
----    ----    ---------   ----    ---------
0.34    0.34    N           0.00    3.33
```

DbVisulizer results:

```
x                       y                       is_equale   x-y                     (x-y)*100
----------------------  ----------------------  ---------   ----------------------  ----------------------
0.34000000000000000000  0.33666666666666666667  N           0.00333333333333333333  3.33333333333333333000
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14227751)

Comment: @ruffp, yes it does. The PO didn't understand how what seems to be equal values are treated as not equal.

Comment: I maintain: this is not a proper answer but a comment. Just look the other answer to see how he explain why this is not working (point to documentation) and how to resolve the OP's question (even it would need some editing/formatting improvement).

Comment: @ruffp, with all the respect, the issue here is the SQL developer displaying, which would cause the same issue even for accurate types as numeric (13,3) when displayed with only 2 digits after the period. I did however changed the wording.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Thank you.. So even though I casted both numbers as double precision inside the parentheses, and then created the condition outside there, Postgres, on the background, is still treating the numbers differently than what I'm seeing?

Comment: @douglas_forsell, please run this `select 100/301::double precision as x,100/299::double precision as y` and tell me what the results are

Comment: @douglas_forsell, p.s. what tool do you use to run the query?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I get 0.332225913621262 and 0.334448160535117 respectively. I'm using pgAdmin III v1.22.1

Comment: @douglas_forsell, can you tell me what are the original types of quantidade and quantidade_reservada?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz "quantidade" and "quantidade_reservada" are numeric(15, 4). And "quantidade_metros", which is the column I'm comparing "quantidade" (numeric) to, is the result of the multiplication of two double precision type columns. In the example, the result showing comes from 2.2 (double precision) times 50 (double precision)

Comment: @douglas_forsell, apparently this is completely pgAdmin issue, not even related to double precision. Please check out this: `with t (x,y) as (select 102/300::numeric(23,20), 101/300::numeric(23,20)) select x, y, case when x=y then '=' else '<>' end is_equale,x-y as "x-y", (x-y)*1000 "(x-y)*100" from t`

Comment: @ruffp, It turns out that I had the right answer from the start, with a slight miss - It was indeed a display issue of the SQL developer (pgAdmin)  but not for double precision type but for numeric type. The double precision type is not relevant to this issue.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz no problem, your answer looks better now after your edit no? anyway for me the right answer is the why (double calculation is not precise) and not the fact that the tool cannot show the full precision (which lead to false assumption, I admit). At the end the error (x-y) is exactly the same between the two tools.